# Using callback with python gdal.RasterizeLayer?

Tags: python, gdal, qgis-plugins

In a QGis python plugin i rasterize a vector layer with this code. All work fine except the callback: no error but nothing happen. The function callbackRasterize is never called

```
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer,
                        options=["ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE", attribute],
                        callback=self.callbackRasterize)
```

I found that using this code, the progress is visualized on standard output, but i can't use it with python:

```
    gdal.RasterizeLayer( .... callback=gdal.TermProgress)
```

How can I do to know when the rasterization process is over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run normal Python, it's all done in sequence, I think. So you need to get the return, or check the result. It'll run inline.

So, you'll know it's finished when it returns! (I think)

Answer (score 5):

Alex is right, the call to `gdal.RasterizeLayer` is synchronous. There's little reason to include a callback unless you wish to obtain progress information, or to cancel the rasterisation part way through.

At a guess I'd say the method signature of your `callbackRasterize` doesn't match that expected by GDAL. Though a little trial and error I got the following to work.

```
def progress_callback(complete, message, unknown):
    print('progress: {}, message: "{}", unknown {}'.format(complete, message, unknown))
    return 1
```

Called by using something like:

```
exitcode = gdal.RasterizeLayer(targetds, [1], source_layer, 
                               burn_values=[1], callback = progress_callback )
```

Prints out the following:

```
progress: 0.0, message: "", unknown None
progress: 0.230125, message: "", unknown None
progress: 0.46025, message: "", unknown None
progress: 0.690375, message: "", unknown None
progress: 0.9205, message: "", unknown None
progress: 1.0, message: "", unknown None
```

Returning a 0 value from the `progress_callback` causes `gdal.RasterizeLayer` to return immediately with a non-zero exit code. I've no idea on what the `unknown` parameter is for, however it is required for the callback to work.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import progressbar as pb

def progress_callback(complete, message, data):
    percent = int(complete * 100)  # round to integer percent
    data.update(percent)  # update the progressbar
    return 1

pbar = pb.ProgressBar(max_value=100).start()

exitcode = gdal.RasterizeLayer(targetds, [1], source_layer, burn_values=[1],
                               callback=progress_callback, callback_data=pbar)

pbar.finish()
```

I'm not 100% sure this works though. With `gdal.Warp` it works a little differently:

```
options = {'callback': progress_callback,
           'callback_data': pbar}
gdal.Warp(dst, src, options=gdal.WarpOptions(**options))
```